# Getting openal audio on nvidia hdmi

Tags: linux, debian, hdmi, nvidia-geforce, alsa

I want to get programs that use openal to send sound over the hdmi output of my nvidia card by using alsa libraries directly.
Here’s my configuration :

```
root@localhost /root % cat /proc/asound/cards               
 0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xef420000 irq 136
 1 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xef080000 irq 17
root@localhost /root %
```

There doesn’t seems a kernel module is loaded for the Nvidia sound card *(in Windows® there’s a specific sound card driver)*. If required, I have no idea of the kernel module to load.

```
root@localhost /root % lsmod | grep snd    
snd_hda_intel          36864  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    90112  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  2
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               114688  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
snd                    86016  8 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
root@localhost /root %
```

So I unmuted spdif inputs in alsamixer:
[image][image]
but the sound is still being sent to my pc speakers instead of hdmi *(maybe it’s normal since there’s no spdif input cable on my graphic card).*

I read about `.asoundrc`, but I have no idea on which device to select *(the hdmi audio )*:

```
root@localhost /root % aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=PCH
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Front speakers
surround21:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Digital
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=PCH,DEV=2
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Digital
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=7
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=PCH,DEV=8
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Digital
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=7
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=PCH,DEV=8
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Digital
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=7
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=8
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=1
    HDA Intel PCH, ALC887-VD Digital
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=3
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=7
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=PCH,DEV=8
    HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2
    Hardware device with all software conversions
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=1
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    HDMI Audio Output
hdmi:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    HDMI Audio Output
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=7
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 1
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=8
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 2
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=9
    HDA NVidia, HDMI 3
    Hardware device with all software conversions
root@localhost /root %
```

Also none of the Nvidia devices of this list works with `aplay -D`

```
root@localhost /root % aplay -Dhw:1 /usr/share/kde4/apps/kolf/sounds/blackhole.wav
aplay: main:788: No such file or directory
```

Looking with strace, it seems it tries to open a non existing device file:

```
root@localhost /root % strace aplay -Dhw:1 /usr/share/kde4/apps/kolf/sounds/blackhole.wav 2>&1 | grep /dev/snd
open("/dev/snd/controlC1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/dev/snd/controlC1", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/dev/snd/pcmC1D0p", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
root@localhost /root %
```

Which looks normal since device 1-1 does not exists:

```
root@localhost /root % cat /proc/asound/devices
  1:        : sequencer
  2: [ 0]   : control
  3: [ 0- 0]: digital audio playback
  4: [ 0- 0]: digital audio capture
  5: [ 0- 1]: digital audio playback
  6: [ 0- 3]: digital audio playback
  7: [ 0- 7]: digital audio playback
  8: [ 0- 8]: digital audio playback
  9: [ 0- 0]: hardware dependent
 10: [ 0- 2]: hardware dependent
 11: [ 1]   : control
 12: [ 1- 3]: digital audio playback
 13: [ 1- 7]: digital audio playback
 14: [ 1- 8]: digital audio playback
 15: [ 1- 9]: digital audio playback
 16: [ 1- 0]: hardware dependent
 33:        : timer
root@localhost /root %
```

**Additionally, I discovered pavucontrol claim the hdmi port is unplugged whereas I have the video signal on the television.**

Comment: In Windows, I just switched the default sound card in the control panel, and it worked. My built‑in intel card also have an hdmi output, but the video doesn’t works on this hdmi port.

Comment: That's because Windows has an equivalent of Pulseaudio (AudioDG.exe) which does all the dirty work – but since you have opted out of that on Linux... Anyway though, have you had any success with other programs besides OpenAL? For example, speaker-test? (Actually, does it work _with_ pulseaudio?)

Comment: @grawity : I couldn’t get any programs sending audio output over hdmi. Remember internally that pusleaudio uses alsa whereas Windows® directly interact with sound drivers. So if it doesn’t works with aplay first, it’s not worth trying pulseaudio.

Comment: Stupid question: You did stop Pulseaudio completely before trying to use ALSA directly? (Check with `ps axu`). If not, it won't work - Pulseaudio takes over all ALSA devices. If you want to run Pulseaudio while still using ALSA for HDMI, you need to configure Pulseaudio to ignore the HDMI ALSA device. I assume you tested that sound over HDMI *with* Pulseaudio works, so one can rule out driver problems with the nvidia card?

Comment: @dirkt yes I did. **Adtionally, I discovered pavucontrol claim the device is unplugged wheras I have the video signal on the television.**

Comment: Ok, so the problem seems to be the nvidia driver. Are you running the closed source `nvidia` driver, or the open source `nouveau` (or maybe still vga framebuffer)? Check in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` for the X driver, and in `dmesg` for the framebuffer driver.

Comment: @dirkt the sound deiver is provided by the `snd_hda_codec_hdmi` kernel module. Otherwise I use the proprietary driver with 4.8.0. The card is geforce 1070